# PivotItem Loaded event fired twice

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

Windows Phone 8, Silverlight. I have a `PivotItem` that is declared in my page XAML under the `ResourceDictionary` of the page, because I don't want it to appear initially and there's no dynamic visibility for PivotItems. When the time comes, I take the object, remove it from resources and add it to a Pivot. It works, but the Load event is, for some reason, fired twice - once on page loading and once when I insert it into the Pivot.

I'd rather have my OnLoaded processing only once.

Is that by design? Is there a way around? Is there a similar event that's fired once upon object initialization (except for the constructor)?

I can work around that by introducing an init-once boolean flag, but still.

Answer (score 1):

You can try OnNavigatedTo. A loaded event can fire on all most any item in the visual tree. If you're looking to collapse items on a pivotItem but no the pivotItem itself, then hook into the parent Grid container.

Ultimately, the Pivot control's children can be removed

myPivotControl.Items.Remove(item);

and you can add an item back in the same manner

myPivotControl.Items.Add(item)

However, I suspect you'll have better results using a different event. The parent pivot has event for adding and removing items. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) will take you to the documentation for the Pivot class. In addition, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.pivotitem%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) will take you to the PivotItem class.

Comment: Removing the item on startup to be re-added later might be the answer I'm looking for. Will accept it it works out.

Comment: Sorry, `Loaded` still fires twice. Also, removing an item from the pivot on startup makes it briefly flicker on the screen - rather jarring.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `PivotItem` collapsed in the beginning and then make it visible when you need it.

Comment: Will the pivot item header be visible on the top of the Pivont control along with the rest of the items? That's not what I'm after...

Comment: No, if you make the item collapsed, it is basically hidden from view and will not be visible on the Pivot control.

Comment: So how do you make an item collapsed? If you set Visibility to Collapsed, the item header is still there, it can be navigated to with a tap, but appears empty. Very jarring.

Comment: Give each Pivot Item an x:Name. This will collapse the entire tree in PivotItem. Also, you can use this trick: NameOfPivotControl.Items.Remove(NameOfPivotControl.Items.Single(p => ((PivotItem)p).Name == "NameOfPivotItem"));